# Swift: Updating UIPageControl from ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I seem to be having some issues getting the UIPageControl to work.

I have a ViewController that holds a ScrollView. This ScrollView loads nib files that can be swiped. See image:

[image]

Here is the code that loads these:

```
self.addChildViewController(vc0)
self.displayReportView.addSubview(vc0.view)
vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        
var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
vc1.view.frame = frame1
self.addChildViewController(vc1)
self.displayReportView.addSubview(vc1.view)
vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

// And so on
...
```

This works fine as in they scroll correctly etc..

Now, on the ViewController (one holding the scrollview) I added the delegate:

```
UIScrollViewDelegate
```

created some variables:

```
 var frame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
 var colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor()]
 var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(50, 300, 200, 20))
```

I added some functions that are needed:

```
func configurePageControl() {
    // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
    
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    
}


// MARK : TO CHANGE WHILE CLICKING ON PAGE CONTROL
func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * displayReportView.frame.size.width
    displayReportView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, 0), animated: true)
}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Now, When I run the app the scrollview dots show, but when I swipe they do not update.

## Question

How do I update the dots to reflect what view is showing?

> let me know if you need anything else from my code to see functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly do what you're describing, if you have a *paging* scroll view; I have an example of it that uses this code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(x/w)
}
```

Except for your `round`, that looks a lot your code, which makes me think that your code *should* work. That makes me think that something else is just misconfigured. *Is* this a paging scroll view? Did you remember to make this object your scroll view's `delegate`? Use logging or a breakpoint to be certain that your `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is even being called in the first place.

However, I would just like to point out that the configuration you are describing is effectively what UIPageViewController gives you for free — a scroll view with view controller views, plus a page control — so you might want to use that instead.

Comment: This is a working downloadable example of a paging horizontal scroll view plus page control, so you might want to try it yourself and then see how your own code differs: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/80551757899141e786b7f601f3879a7b450923c2/bk2ch07p372paging/ch20p676paging/ViewController.swift

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply. I am struggling to get this to work still and my little vain on my temple is about to burst. blurgh... I have uploaded the project here: https://jumpshare.com/v/2Lq5U0KW2ExBWezcw7o3 - do you think you could take a look and give me some pointers? (Gets on knees, prays and begs )

Comment: sorry if it's super cheeky asking you to view the project. For clarification Im trying to get it so that when the user scrolls either left or right the pagecontrol will update accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JamesG - I downloaded your project and looked at and the correct answer is right there in my answer. Please read what I said (in the second paragraph) and think about it! Hint: I was able to get your project working (i.e. the page control updates) by adding one line of code in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Oh my god!! the delegate. Sooo sorry for hassling you You saved my bacon

Comment: P.s forgot to save thank you. :) I have bookmarked your books page - my mother will be buying me that :-p :)

Comment: :) Sorry to be so hard-nosed, but I'm a teacher - it's my job to torture you into learning!

Comment: i recommend you to  use UIcollectionView bz its a subclass of scrollview and you do not bother to set explicitly content width and height. you get idea how to do see my some sort of work https://github.com/ChandramaniPatel/CustomePageControll

Comment: By the way, if you want the page control to update when one page occupies more than 50% of the view, you can replace the third line of the function with `pageControl.currentPage = Int(round(x/w))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the scroll view with a `UICollectionView`. This way you get paging for free, and it will be better, because paging will work out of the box, without you having to calculate the frame offsets.

Be sure to set `collectionView.pagingEnabled = true`

To get the current page number, do `collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().first?.item`

To change the page:

`collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(newIndexPath, atScrollPosition: CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)`

Comment: I would rather find a way to do it with what I have got. Thanks for the advice though, will consider this for next app. :)